# How do I pass access tokens from express server to react app, in a Oauth application?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, oauth

I'm building a react app with an express server, and using OAuth 2 to securely access intuit APIs. The express server sends the authorization request, and then receives the authorization code at `localhost:8000/callback` where it's converted into an access token. The problem is that this access token is only accessible in the express app - so how do I send it to my react front end, so I can use it to securely make REST calls from react? 
I've look at similar questions and there seems to be two solutions: use JWT, or store the access token on local storage. I'm just not sure where to start with either of these approaches, since I'm new to learning auth.

Anyway, my app structured so that my react app runs off a dev server at `localhost:3000`, and proxies request to my express server at `localhost:8000`.

Here's the express app:

```
'use strict';

require('dotenv').config();

/**
 * Require the dependencies
 * @type {*|createApplication}
 */
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var path = require('path');
var OAuthClient = require('intuit-oauth');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var ngrok =  (process.env.NGROK_ENABLED==="true") ? require('ngrok'):null;


/**
 * Configure View and Handlebars
 */
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.use(bodyParser.json())

var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false });

/**
 * App Variables
 * @type {null}
 */
var oauth2_token_json = null,
    redirectUri = '';


/**
 * Instantiate new Client
 * @type {OAuthClient}
 */

var oauthClient = null;


/**
 * Home Route
 */
app.get('/', function(req, res) {

    res.render('index');
});

/**
 * Get the AuthorizeUri
 */
app.get('/authUri', urlencodedParser, function(req,res) {

    oauthClient = new OAuthClient({
        clientId: '*****',
        clientSecret: '*****',
        environment: 'sandbox',
        redirectUri: 'http://localhost:8000/callback'
    });

    var authUri = oauthClient.authorizeUri({scope:[OAuthClient.scopes.Accounting],state:'intuit-test'});
    res.send(authUri);
});


/**
 * Handle the callback to extract the `Auth Code` and exchange them for `Bearer-Tokens`
 */
app.get('/callback', function(req, res) {

    oauthClient.createToken(req.url)
       .then(function(authResponse) {
             oauth2_token_json = JSON.stringify(authResponse.getJson(), null,2);
         })
        .catch(function(e) {
             console.error(e);
         });

    res.redirect('http://localhost:3000')
});




/**
 * getCompanyInfo ()
 */
app.get('/getCompanyInfo', function(req,res){


    var companyID = oauthClient.getToken().realmId;

    var url = oauthClient.environment == 'sandbox' ? OAuthClient.environment.sandbox : OAuthClient.environment.production ;

    oauthClient.makeApiCall({url: url + 'v3/company/' + companyID +'/companyinfo/' + companyID})
        .then(function(authResponse){
            console.log("The response for API call is :"+JSON.stringify(authResponse));
            res.send(JSON.parse(authResponse.text()));
        })
        .catch(function(e) {
            console.error(e);
        });
});

app.get('/test', (req,res) => {
    res.send('hello from server')
})


const server = app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8000, () => {
    console.log(` Server listening on port ${server.address().port}`);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The `/authUri` request is made by the *browser* via the proxy server, and its response is a [redirect](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#AuthResponse) to the callback URL. Therefore, the callback URL must also be on the frontend server (i.e., `http://localhost:3000/callback`). The proxy server will then forward the `/callback` request to the express server, and the express server can put the access token in an (HTTP only) cookie that is sent back (via the proxy server) to the browser.

```js
app.get('/callback', function(req, res) {
  oauthClient.createToken(req.url)
  .then(function(authResponse) {
    res.cookie("session", authResponse.getJson().access_token,
      {path: "/", httpOnly: true});
    res.redirect('http://localhost:3000');
  });
});
```

Verify that the proxy server preserves both sent and received cookies.

Then with every subsequent request, the browser will send the cookie (via the proxy server) back to the express server.

(Unlike the local storage, an HTTP only cookie is not accessible via JavaScript, which gives extra protection against cross-site scripting attacks.)